# create different list variable names using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, iteration

I am looking to use cross validation for 3 different ML classifiers and would like to get all results without repetitive code

```
model_01 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 2, random_state = 0)
model_02 = XGBClassifier(max_depth = 2, n_estimators=200)
model_03 = LogisticRegression()
classifier= [model_01,model_02,model_03] 

for i in classifier: 
  kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=random_seed)
  cross_val_f1_score_lst = []
  cross_val_accuracy_lst = []
  cross_val_recall_lst = []
  cross_val_precision_lst = []
```

I wont go through the ML code since it is not necessary for this problem. But I would like to append 5 entries for each list given above. With all the entries suggested above, I would want separate set of lists for all three different classifiers mentioned above (with list names such as cross_val_f1_score_lst_model_01/02/03 etc). The rest of the relevant code for one classifier iteration is given below.

```
  #mean values for all metrics
  cross_val_recall_lst.append(recall_score(target_val, validation_preds))
  cross_val_accuracy_lst.append(accuracy_score(target_val, validation_preds))
  cross_val_precision_lst.append(precision_score(target_val, validation_preds))
  cross_val_f1_score_lst.append(f1_score(target_val, validation_preds))

  print('Cross validated overall financial loss: {}'.format(np.mean(cross_val_financial_loss_lst)))
  print('Cross validated accuracy: {}'.format(np.mean(cross_val_accuracy_lst)))
  print('Cross validated recall score: {}'.format(np.mean(cross_val_recall_lst)))
  print('Cross validated precision score: {}'.format(np.mean(cross_val_precision_lst)))
  print('Cross validated f1_score: {}'.format(np.mean(cross_val_f1_score_lst)))
```

Any solution will be highly appreciated. Feel free if I am using any incorrect terminology.

Comment: Don't dynamically create variables, *use a container* like a list or a dict

Comment: could you possibly give an example?